# serialization versus file writing

Tags: serialization, save, protocol-buffers

I am trying to understand serialization and deserialization but still have some doubts. How it is different than writing a file to the disk. If I want to store some data on the disk or send it across the network, can i not write the data using

```
open(filename), write(filename) and close(filename)?
```

This would store the data on the disk in the filename in text or binary format depending upon whichever mode i choose. I can then send this file across the network.

How is this different from serialization?
How this is different from protocol buffer?

Please help me and others nail this concept down once and for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization):

> In computer science, in the context of data storage, serialization is the process of translating data structures or object state into a format that can be stored (for example, in a file or memory buffer, or transmitted across a network connection link) and reconstructed later in the same or another computer environment.

So, it doesn't matter how you're doing it (how you store the file, how you send it, etc.), the important thing is that you're able to reconstruct (deserialize) the original object from the transitional state.

Let's say you bought the [Lego Millenium Falcon](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Millennium-Falcon-7965#BVRRWidgetID) on internet. This is a great Object, but it isn't possible to send it to you just constructed. So at Lego they deconstruct it and they put it into a special box (serialization). The box shape depends on which channel they are using to send it to you. For example, if they bring it to you by hand they will use a handbag; if they are using an express courier they will use a box compatible with the specific express courier used (JSON, XML, YAML...). After a week you get the box so you unpack the box and happily construct the Millennium Falcon (deserialization). After several weeks you need to store the Falcon in your closet, but it is too big for the shelf so you deconstruct it and you put the pieces inside a box that fit the shelf (a file?). After some time you take it back and again reconstruct it.
You can deconstruct/pack-unpack/construct the object every time you want. 
As in computer science you can use several media to store/send the box, you can ship it, you can bring it and in the future you would teleport it.

About protocol buffer you can think about it as a special box that can adapt to the object you have to send and it can be packed/unpacked by multiple person, even if they do not speak the same language.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that part. I was wondering what is point of putting more names for this like protocol buffer. Any ideas

Comment: I tried to make an example, I hope it could clarify the things a bit.